# save items in an array to active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[{"id"=>"2", "reply"=>"ok"}, {"id"=>"3", "reply"=>"ok"}, {"id"=>"4", "reply"=>"ok"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"6", "reply"=>"2"}]
```

now I'm trying to save it like this:

```
current_user.answers.transaction do

  success = params[:answers].map(&:save)
  unless sucess.all?
    errored = params[:answers].select { |b| !b.errors.blank? }
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end

end
```

but that results in

```
undefined method `save' for {"id"=>"2", "reply"=>"ok"}:ActionController::Parameters
```

does anybody know how I can save each item?

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :comments

  validates :reply, :question_id, :week_number, presence: true


end
```

Comment: Realize that `params` is a Hash, not an ActiveRecord, so #save doesn't exist as a method.  You could still use `map` but will have to write a block for it.

Comment: any suggestions, I'm trying to achieve that now but unable to do so.

Comment: show your `Answer` model

Comment: You could possibly write something like `success = params[answers].map { |answer| record = SomeAnswerModel.find(answer[:id]).update(answer) }`.  As @AbM suggests, we'd need to see the model to comment further.

Comment: @AbM I've updated my answer.

Comment: @rdnewman the ID in the array, is actually the associated question id

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just send it a block... so you can try:

```
current_user.answers.transaction do
  success = params[:answers].map do |hash|
    object = Model.new(hash)
    object.save
  end
  unless success.all?
    errored = params[:answers].select { |b| !b.errors.blank? }
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Realize that `Model` needs to be the name of the model you're trying to instantiate objects with.

but, that's only if you're making new objects, which generally won't be the case of you've set the `id` attribute already

```
current_user.answers.transaction do
  success = params[:answers].map do |hash|
    object = Model.find(hash["id"])
    object.update_attributes(hash)
  end
  unless success.all?
    errored = params[:answers].select { |b| !b.errors.blank? }
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Hope this helps